# NetBeans - Cannot Connect To Server - ProxyHTTP

Tags: http, netbeans, proxy, vps, centos6

I'm stuck.

I've reinstalled CentOS6 onto my VPS. Set it up as a LAMP server.

When I create a new project in NetBeans and try to connect to the server i get the error:

"**Cannot connect to server [ipaddress]**

**(Cause: ProxyHTTP: com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: java.net.UnknownHostException: http:127.0.0.1**)"

Any Ideas?

Thankyou,
Joe

Answer (score 0):

Seems you are using wrong scheme for uploading the files. You shouldn't include the http:// URI scheme in your configuration. Have you set up the FTP server?

Answer (score 0):

In netbeans go to **"Tools->Options"**. Here in **"Proxy Settings"** section select **"No proxy"** and click **OK**. This removed this error for me.